# How should i store and compare date time in android?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-datepicker

I am taking date from datepicker and time from timepicker. I create a date object out of it and store it as milliseconds in db. I am using sqlite database. I want to retrieve records for a particular date from db. If I compare field stored as milliseconds directly it will include time of the day also. How should I go about this complete thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can then compare times just as in your example

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time2 = ...;

if (time2 < time1) {
```